# Resizing partitions for EC2 FreeBSD instance without reboot

Tags: partition, freebsd, amazon-ec2

I modified the volume size for a partition on AWS Console and it does not show up in `gpart show`. It does show up after the reboot. I didn't have to reboot an Ubuntu instance to resize. Am I missing any steps here or is reboot required for FreeBSD 11.0 instances in this case? Can we do a service restart or something that can avoid reboot?

Before reboot:

```
=>       3  20971509  ada0  GPT  (10G)
         3       125     1  freebsd-boot  (63K)
       128  20971384     2  freebsd-ufs  (10G)
```

After reboot:

```
=>       3  20971509  ada0  GPT  (40G) [CORRUPT]
         3       125     1  freebsd-boot  (63K)
       128  20971384     2  freebsd-ufs  (10G)
```

Comment: did you run gpart recover?

Comment: I think `gpart recover` did not do anything before the reboot. I do not remember the error but I think it was something like 'nothing to recover'. After reboot, the output was something like `recovered`. I can try reproducing it again

Answer (score 2):

The problem we are having here is that while the low-level nvme driver recognizes the increased volume size:

```
# nvmecontrol devlist
 ...
 nvme2: Amazon Elastic Block Store
    nvme2ns1 (655360MB)
 ...
```

(this is from an example I am just working, where I resized 260 GB to 640 GB.)

The gpart layer still believes the physical disk has the old size.

```
# gpart show nvd2
=>       40  545259440  nvd2  GPT  (260G)
         40  545259440     1  freebsd-ufs  (260G)
```

What is missing is something that nudges gpart to re-check its idea of the size.

And the only way I have found to do that is to detach and then re-attach the device.

[FreeBSD on AWS: resizing nvme disk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/664250/freebsd-on-aws-resizing-nvme-disk)